# What's the difference between java bytecode astore_1 and astore_2

Tags: java, bytecode

What's the difference between java bytecode `astore_1` and `astore_2` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The instructions `astore_n`, for small values of `n`, are just shorthand equivalents for `astore n`. Either version stores what's on top of the stack into local variable `n`.

Answer (score 5):

`astore_1` is the same as `astore 1`, and `astore_2` is the same as `astore 2`, except that `astore_1` and `astore_2` are one byte each, whereas `astore` is a two-byte instruction.