# Does the Java foreach loop create a new object?

Tags: java, foreach, garbage-collection

Will Java create a new object each time a foreach loop is entered?
I'm not talking about each iteration, but if you have a foreach loop that is used multiple times, is it creating objects each time?

Simple Example:

```
for(Object o : Objects)
{
    for(Object p : Objects2)
    {
    }
}
```

**Would there only be one `p` per execution, or would `p` be instantiated for each `Object o`?
Does the Garbage Collector have to recover an object from the foreach loop each time it is exited?**

More specifically, I'm writing some Android based game code.  It will iterate over all the game objects at a given rate per second, or as fast as it can depending on the circumstances.

It may be a case of premature optimization, but if using an explicit `for` or `while` loop can guarantee me that I won't have excess garbage collection from my loops, then I can establish that as a coding standard for the project.

More specifically:

```
public void update()
{
    for(GameObject gObj : gameObjects)
    {
        gObj.update();
    }
}
```

With `update()` being called from a thread designed to make the calls based on the timing I described before.

**Update:**
I am asking if there is a new Reference `p` being created for each `o` in `Objects`.  Not if it copies the objects in `Objects2`.  So does the VM have to create a new Reference `p`, and then does it collect that reference between iterations of the outter loop? And more specifically in my case, does it collect the reference between method calls?

**Update:**
From comments on Matt Ball's answer.
Which would create less Garbage Collection work?

```
//Loop just to have it run a number of times
//Could be running the inner foreach numerous time for any reason
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    for(Object o : Objects)
    {
        o.update();
    }
}
```

vs.

```
Iterator<Object> iter;
//Loop just to have it run a number of times
//Could be running the inner foreach numerous time for any reason
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    iter = Objects.iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext());
    {
        iter.getNext().update();
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Comparing scopes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class TestLoops
{
    public static Iterator<Object> it;
    public static ArrayList<Object> objects;

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

        it = objects.iterator();
        it = objects.iterator();

            //Every time we start a foreach loop, does it creates a new reference?
        Iterator<Object> newIt1 = objects.iterator();
        Iterator<Object> newIt2 = objects.iterator();       

    }
}
```

Produces this Bytecode:

```
public class TestLoops {
public static java.util.Iterator<java.lang.Object> it;

public static java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object> objects;

public TestLoops();

    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/util/ArrayList
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
       7: putstatic     #4                  // Field objects:Ljava/util/ArrayList;
      10: getstatic     #4                  // Field objects:Ljava/util/ArrayList;
      13: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/util/ArrayList.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
      16: putstatic     #6                  // Field it:Ljava/util/Iterator;
      19: getstatic     #4                  // Field objects:Ljava/util/ArrayList;
      22: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/util/ArrayList.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
      25: putstatic     #6                  // Field it:Ljava/util/Iterator;
      28: getstatic     #4                  // Field objects:Ljava/util/ArrayList;
      31: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/util/ArrayList.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
      34: astore_1
      35: getstatic     #4                  // Field objects:Ljava/util/ArrayList;
      38: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/util/ArrayList.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
      41: astore_2
      42: return
}
```

Comment: @codeMan yes, that's the question I understand it doesn't make copies of the objects in the collections. Updating now.

Comment: Your test cases simply do not make sense to me. I don't see how that code is supposed to demonstrate the difference between a for-each and an explicit-iterator loop. In fact, `TestLoops#main()` doesn't make any sense at all to me. What about my answer is not sufficient for you? And no, bytecode does not show GC because GC is left to the VM. Oh, and the `astore_n`s are for storing values as local variables: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6983641/139010.

Comment: Your use of the term "references" is a misapplication. The code "has to make two separate references `3` and `4`" because _you have two separate local variables._

Comment: @MattBall It was a misapplication because I didn't apply the scopes properly. I updated the code, there is an iterator that exists in the static class scope. If the foreach loops have to create a reference for an iterator each time they are entered, then they create new references that have to be destroyed.  Whereas maintaining a reference at static scope so it doesn't go out of scope when the foreach loops ends means we don't create/destroy references constantly.  This is how I'm seeing this, the code in your answer also doesn't apply scope.

Comment: Please don't call it "create a reference" — what you're really talking about is creating/reusing local variables. The fact that the variable is a reference type (rather than primitive) is irrelevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no magical object construction that happens with a for-each loop. This syntax:

```
for(Object o : Objects)
{
    for(Object p : Objects2)
    {
    }
}
```

is **only** shorthand for this:

```
for(Iterator<Object> iter = Objects.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
{
    Object o = iter.next();
    for(Iterator<Object> iter2 = Objects2.iterator(); iter2.hasNext();)
    {
        Object p = iter2.next();
    }
}
```

---

> If would there be an `iter2` reference created for every object I had in `Objects`?

That depends on where `Objects2` comes from. Does it come from `o`? It also depends on how `Objects2.iterator()` is implemented. `Iterable#iterator()` is expected to return independent iterators, which means that `Objects2.iterator()` would almost certainly return a new `Iterator` for each invocation. But that does *not* say anything about whether or not iterating through the objects in `Objects2` (using `iter2`) creates other new objects.

This sounds like premature optimization, overall.

---

> Which would create less Garbage Collection work?

**Neither.** The enhanced for loop (aka for-each loop) is simply syntactic sugar. The bytecode produced by the compiler is identical. [Complete example:](https://github.com/mjball/Stack-Overflow-Q-A/tree/master/q14640184/src/com/stackoverflow)

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class Question14640184
{
    public void enhancedForLoop(Iterable<Object> objects1, Iterable<Object> objects2)
    {
        for(Object o1 : objects1)
        {
            for(Object o2 : objects2)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }

    public void iteratorForLoop(Iterable<Object> objects1, Iterable<Object> objects2)
    {
        for(Iterator<Object> iter1 = objects1.iterator(); iter1.hasNext();)
        {
            Object o1 = iter1.next();
            for(Iterator<Object> iter2 = objects2.iterator(); iter2.hasNext();)
            {
                Object o2 = iter2.next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compile:

```
✗ javac Question14640184.java
✗ javap -c Question14640184
Compiled from "Question14640184.java"
public class com.stackoverflow.Question14640184 extends java.lang.Object{
public com.stackoverflow.Question14640184();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public void enhancedForLoop(java.lang.Iterable, java.lang.Iterable);
  Code:
   0:   aload_1
   1:   invokeinterface #2,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/lang/Iterable.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
   6:   astore_3
   7:   aload_3
   8:   invokeinterface #3,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
   13:  ifeq    57
   16:  aload_3
   17:  invokeinterface #4,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
   22:  astore  4
   24:  aload_2
   25:  invokeinterface #2,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/lang/Iterable.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
   30:  astore  5
   32:  aload   5
   34:  invokeinterface #3,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
   39:  ifeq    54
   42:  aload   5
   44:  invokeinterface #4,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
   49:  astore  6
   51:  goto    32
   54:  goto    7
   57:  return

public void iteratorForLoop(java.lang.Iterable, java.lang.Iterable);
  Code:
   0:   aload_1
   1:   invokeinterface #2,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/lang/Iterable.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
   6:   astore_3
   7:   aload_3
   8:   invokeinterface #3,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
   13:  ifeq    57
   16:  aload_3
   17:  invokeinterface #4,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
   22:  astore  4
   24:  aload_2
   25:  invokeinterface #2,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/lang/Iterable.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
   30:  astore  5
   32:  aload   5
   34:  invokeinterface #3,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
   39:
```

So like I said, **the for-each loop is *only* [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).**

> it's something I'm just fixated on.

Move on, friendo.

Comment: So my question here is this, would there be an `iter2` reference created for every object I had in `Objects`?

Comment: @Chris Depends on what `next()` of iterator does, is might just get an already existing object from a collection, or create a new one every time it is called.

Comment: @MattBall this still isn't answering my question though. If `Objects` had 500 items. Would the VM create and then destroy 500 References to the iterator returned by Objects2? I realize there's no new literal objects created, but there still has to be `Reference` objects that allow `iter2` to point to the iterator that's returned.

Comment: @MattBall I agree it's tending to premature optimization, however, now it's something I'm just fixated on. Also, if we figure out which way is best, it's not a design change it's just a coding standard so the optimization has almost no cost to implement.

Comment: @MattBall updated the question, hoping that gets more specifically to what I'm wondering.

Comment: @Chris edited (and you don't need to `@user` to the person whose post you're commenting on; the post owner is always notified)

Comment: I can't get my mind past how the compiler could create a reference at a scope above the for loop unless it's explicitly listed there. And unless references are immutable, a properly scoped reference object would not go out of scope at the end of each complete iteration of the foreach loop.

Comment: I'm building a test up now, will post back.

Comment: I updated with some tests and the bytecode as well. I really do think there is a creation and collection that happens when you use the implicit foreach loop versus defining an iterator in a scope above the loop itself.

Comment: As per my comment in the OP. I don't think the latest set of code illustrates what I'm questioning. Yes, what you have there is syntactically the same, but what if we could pull `Iterator<Object> iter2` out, so that the inner loop didn't have to create a reference to an Iterator each time it started? Could it be made to set an existing reference, hence preventing undue garbage collection?

Comment: @Chris: The position in memory where the reference to the iterator is stored will get reused anyway.  That's free.

Comment: @LouisWasserman So will the Garbage Collector have to do any work for that memory to be reused?

Comment: The _reference_ to the iterator?  No work at all.  The iterator object itself won't get reused, but in practice, creating lots of short-lived iterators and letting them get GC'd is _faster_ than trying to reuse the same iterator object.

Comment: @LouisWasserman are you sure that's true for Dalvik as well as HotSpot? I'm much less familiar with the performance characteristics of Dalvik than HotSpot...

Comment: @Chris The inner Iterator can't be hoisted in general because it might depend on a value created by the outer loop. If it doesn't, HotSpot may well hoist it. But this isn't a property of for-each, but of HotSpot.

Comment: @MattBall: I concede that that's probably not true for Android.  It's definitely true for HotSpot, though, where long-lived objects get promoted into older generations where they're harder to GC.

Comment: @EJP the OP is asking about Android in this particular question, to the JVM is Dalvik, not HotSpot.

Comment: So, is the consensus I'm seeing that it depends on the VM. And that it may depend too much on specific circumstances to have a clear cut answer?

Comment: @Chris it's irrelevant that it depends on the VM, since you asked your question in the context of Android, and Dalvik is _the_ Android JVM. The only thing aside from the JVM that it depends on is exactly how you write the code, and I see absolutely no compelling reason to write anything other than idiomatic Java here. Frankly, I fail to understand why we are even still discussing this.

Comment: @Chris if you really think that keeping around an `Iterator` variable will be more performant (because of less GC work, or whatever) you should prove it with benchmarking.

Comment: I'm planning to do that when I get a chance. I'll post the results, but the recent comments reminded me that the VMs are much smarter than I am.  So regardless of what the compiler may create, the VM will do what it thinks is best. Hence why I'm thinking specific circumstances affect the performance more than the code. Thanks for you patience.

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on what the Iterable returns. If it creates a new object, so be it. If not, not. In the case of an array, for example, the elements already exist, so no object is created. Same applies to most Collections.

The one case where it almost certainly creates a new object is where the Iterable itself is the result of a function call, for example:

```
for (Object o : xyz.getIterable())
```

But this isn't a property of the for-each loop but of the function call.