# libGDX does foreach create an object?

Tags: java, foreach, libgdx

Im learning by these tutourials g3d: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/using-materials-with-libgdx/

Now I have heard that the foreach loop creates an object and thats bad to use in the render method.

Example:

```
private PerspectiveCamera cam;
private CameraInputController camController;
private Shader shader;
private Model model;
private Array<ModelInstance> instances = new Array<ModelInstance>();
private ModelBatch modelBatch;

@Override
public void show() {
    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(2f, 2f, 2f);
    cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    cam.near = 1f;
    cam.far = 300f;
    cam.update();

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);

    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    model = modelBuilder.createSphere(2f, 2f, 2f, 20, 20,
            new Material(),
            VertexAttributes.Usage.Position |
                    VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal |
                    VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates);

    for (int x = -5; x <= 5; x+=2) {
        for (int z = -5; z <= 5; z+=2) {
            instances.add(new ModelInstance(model, x, 0, z));
        }
    }

    shader = new TestShader();
    shader.init();

    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    camController.update();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    for (ModelInstance instance : instances) {
        modelBatch.render(instance, shader);
    }
    modelBatch.end();

}
```

1. Is this true does it create an Object?
2. What would be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not create an Object. The for-each loop is simply a syntactical shortcut. See [Does the Java foreach loop create a new object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640184/does-the-java-foreach-loop-create-a-new-object)

Comment: It should be noted that in _this_ case the `foreach` doesn't create a new object, but only because the `Array` class [doesn't create a new Iterator for each call to `iterator()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html#iterator--).
If we were using a collection from java.util, which AFAIK all do create a new iterator for each call to `iterator()`, we would indeed be creating garbage in each `foreach` loop.